How to Download Files from a Specific Nested Folder in SharePoint Using Microsoft Graph API?
I'm working on a C# application that downloads files from a SharePoint library using the Microsoft Graph API. The issue that the API returns null value object when I try to access the nested folder because the logged-in user only has access to a specific nested folder within the library.
If user has access on Document /Blackout(folder/ Then code is returning value. But If user has access only on Native Draft then value object is blank.
jsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("value").EnumerateArray()


public async Task<bool> DownloadDrive(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    OutputWindow.Info($"Start DownloadDrive.", _resultText);
    string siteId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    string libraryUrl = "https://XXXXXX/sites/{sitename}/Shared%20Documents";
    string driveId = await GetDriveId(siteId, libraryUrl);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(driveId))
    {
        OutputWindow.Info($"SharePoint Library under {libraryUrl} could not be found.", _resultText);
        return false;
    }

    if (Directory.Exists(_localFolder))
    {
        Directory.Delete(_localFolder, true);
    }
    Directory.CreateDirectory(_localFolder);

    await DownloadLibrary(driveId, _localFolder);
    return true;
}

private async Task<string> GetDriveId(string siteId, string libraryUrl)
{
    var requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives";
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(responseContent);
    foreach (var drive in jsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("value").EnumerateArray())
    {
        if (drive.GetProperty("webUrl").GetString() == libraryUrl)
        {
            return drive.GetProperty("id").GetString();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private async Task DownloadLibrary(string driveId, string path)
{
    var requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root/children";
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(responseContent);
    foreach (var driveItem in jsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("value").EnumerateArray())
    {
        await DownloadDriveItem(driveItem, driveId, path);
    }
}

private async Task DownloadDriveItem(JsonElement driveItem, string driveId, string path)
{
    string itemName = driveItem.GetProperty("name").GetString() ?? string.Empty;
    OutputWindow.Info($"{itemName}", _resultText);
    if (!driveItem.TryGetProperty("@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl", out var downloadUrl))
    {
        OutputWindow.Info($"Downloading the folder {driveItem.GetProperty("webUrl").GetString()}", _resultText);

        var folderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, driveItem.GetProperty("name").GetString());
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

        var requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{driveItem.GetProperty("id").GetString()}/children";
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(responseContent);
        foreach (var childItem in jsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("value").EnumerateArray())
        {
            await DownloadDriveItem(childItem, driveId, folderPath);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        OutputWindow.Info($"Downloading the file {driveItem.GetProperty("webUrl").GetString()}", _resultText);

        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, driveItem.GetProperty("name").GetString());
        var fileResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(downloadUrl.GetString());
        fileResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        await using var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        await fileResponse.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}


Always check the HTTP status in the response to determine the error.   You are probably getting a 400 error like 401.  You are probably having a routing issue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

@jdweng response code is 200. And I have added response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() to ensure success code

Either there is a bug in the server code that returning 200 instead of an error, or the query is returning not results.  The code is working with different credentials and should return an error when using wrong credentials.  So I suspect there is two issues 1) The server code should be returning an error 2) The credentials for the route in server needs to be modified to accept the user/role that you are using.  Or the user needs to be added to the role.

In the Shared Documents folder, there is a folder structure that includes folders named A1, A11, and A111. When using an API with the credentials of a user who has permission on the A1 folder, the API call returns the correct value object. However, when using the credentials of a second user who only has access to the A111 folder, the API call does not return any value. This issue is related to the user's permissions, and it is unclear if there is a way to specify the folder path in the API call to directly process the A111 folder.

Run the test in following and see what happens : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sharing-and-permissions/fix-site-user-id-mismatch#resolution
